# My Dataframe all have NaN except the last column

Tags: python, json, pandas, loops

I'm trying to loop over multiple JSON data and then for each value in list add it to the DataFrame. For each JSON data, I create a column header. I seem to always only get the data for the last column, so there is clearly something wrong with the way I append the data I believe.

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
df = pd.DataFrame()


timePeriod = 120


for x in range(10):
    try:
        data = cg.get_coin_market_chart_by_id(id=geckoList[x], 
                                 vs_currency ='btc', days = 'timePeriod')

        for y in range(timePeriod):
            df = df.append({geckoList[x]: data['prices'][y][1]}, 
                                          ignore_index= True)
        print(geckoList[x])

    except:
        pass
```

Geckolist example:

```
['bitcoin',
 'ethereum',
 'xrp',
 'bitcoin-cash',
 'litecoin',
 'binance-coin']
```

Example JSON of one the coins:

```
'prices': [[1565176840078, 0.029035263522626625],
  [1565177102060, 0.029079747150763842],
  [1565177434439, 0.029128983083947863],
  [1565177700686, 0.029136960678700433],
  [1565178005716, 0.0290826667213779],
  [1565178303855, 0.029173025688296675],
  [1565178602640, 0.029204331218623796],
  [1565178911561, 0.029211943928343167],
```

The expected result would be a DataFrame with columns and rows of data for each crypto coin. Right now only the last column shows data

Currently, it looks like this:

```
    bitcoin ethereum bitcoin-cash
0   NaN    NaN    0.33  
1   NaN    NaN    0.32  
2   NaN    NaN    0.21  
3   NaN    NaN    0.22  
4   NaN    NaN    0.25  
5   NaN    NaN    0.26  
6   NaN    NaN    0.22  
7   NaN    NaN    0.22
```

Comment: Did you check the contents of data? Unfortunately it's a bit hard to help you because your example is not runable.

Comment: Yes the data looks fine example (added example of JSON)

Comment: `NAN` means `Not a Number`, so double check for letter or *not a number* characters.

Comment: It's strange since If I extend the list Bitcoin-cash shows NaN and the now the last column shows data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I found the issue.

The problem is you append data structures row by row that contained only one column to the frame, so all the other columns were filled with `NaN`. What i *think* you want is to join the columns by their timestamp. This is what i did in my example below. Let me know if this is what you need:

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
import pandas as pd

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()

timePeriod = 120

gecko_list = ['bitcoin',
              'ethereum',
              'xrp',
              'bitcoin-cash',
              'litecoin',
              'binance-coin']

data = {}
for coin in gecko_list:
    try:
        nested_lists = cg.get_coin_market_chart_by_id(
            id=coin, vs_currency='btc', days='timePeriod')['prices']
        data[coin] = {}
        data[coin]['timestamps'], data[coin]['values'] = zip(*nested_lists)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('coin: ' + coin)

frame_list = [pd.DataFrame(
              data[coin]['values'],
              index=data[coin]['timestamps'],
              columns=[coin])
              for coin in gecko_list
              if coin in data]

df = pd.concat(frame_list, axis=1).sort_index()
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='ms')

print(df)
```

This gets me the output

```
                         bitcoin  ethereum  bitcoin-cash  litecoin
2019-08-07 12:20:14.490      NaN       NaN      0.029068       NaN
2019-08-07 12:20:17.420      NaN       NaN           NaN  0.007890
2019-08-07 12:20:21.532      1.0       NaN           NaN       NaN
2019-08-07 12:20:27.730      NaN  0.019424           NaN       NaN
2019-08-07 12:24:45.309      NaN       NaN      0.029021       NaN
...                          ...       ...           ...       ...
2019-08-08 12:15:47.548      NaN       NaN           NaN  0.007578
2019-08-08 12:18:41.000      NaN  0.018965           NaN       NaN
2019-08-08 12:18:44.000      1.0       NaN           NaN       NaN
2019-08-08 12:18:54.000      NaN       NaN           NaN  0.007577
2019-08-08 12:18:59.000      NaN       NaN      0.028144       NaN

[1153 rows x 4 columns]
```

This is the data i get if i switch `days` to 180.

[image]

To get daily data, use the `groupby function`:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).mean()
```

On a data frame of 5 days, this gives me:

```
            bitcoin  ethereum  bitcoin-cash  litecoin
2019-08-03      1.0  0.020525      0.031274  0.008765
2019-08-04      1.0  0.020395      0.031029  0.008583
2019-08-05      1.0  0.019792      0.029805  0.008360
2019-08-06      1.0  0.019511      0.029196  0.008082
2019-08-07      1.0  0.019319      0.028837  0.007854
2019-08-08      1.0  0.018949      0.028227  0.007593
```

Comment: Thanks for it! On  "for coin in gecko_list" I'm getting ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! Question why do you initially use timePeriod then timestamp?

Comment: I did not really think about what that API returns. What does the parameter `days` control?

Comment: It refers to the number of days worth of data you want (ie, 5 days) means the last 5 days of data

Comment: Ok, but the data that is returned is a list of `[timestamp, value]` pairs, right? That's what your example JSON above looks like to me at least.

Comment: yes, you are correct. If you request min 120 days of data then it will return 1 data point per day. If less multiple data points per day. The issue still remains for me keep getting error as mentioned above in comments :(. I copy pasted your code  moreorless.

Comment: Could you copy it entirely into a fresh file and try again? If you copied parts, i suspect that there are incompatibilities with variable names or such. I posted a complete script that should run as is. What version of python and pandas are you using, respectively?

Comment: Did the indentation perhaps get messed up when you copy-pasted?

Comment: To only get daily data (last trading point), how do you suggest to adjust your code?

Comment: You could either request daywise data from the API and slice the time range you need out of that or you could use the `groupby` functionality in pandas. Example: `df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).mean()`. You can get the last row of a frame by simply calling `df.tail(1)`.